# Force users (developers) to remove default styles or add no default styles and look bad

Tags: default, style, plugins

I'm not sure if this question is in bounds, as the users are the developers that will use my plugin.

**Example:**

I'm creating a simple modal plugin, it has a header, body, and footer area like a lot of other modals. Typically most modals will want styles applied such as padding on the inside of the body so that text doesn't run up against the border. However, you can imagine cases where developers wouldn't want that padding such as a full size image modal. When packaging this plugin for the developer is it best to:

**Apply default styling, such as padding to the body, under the presumption that many users would want it that way, and forcing those who don't to override it.**

or,

**Apply no default styling leaving it a blank template, so users can add only what they need. But out of the box it looks bad.**

Answer (score 1):

First option seems the best, since most of the developers look for something "quick", that doesn't require a lot of work upon it, either because of lack of time or just because because they doesn't know/want to style it from zero.

So I'd go with the **first option**.

Answer (score 0):

As a developer, I would always look for something configurable, so your **first option** would be preferred.

Comment: The second option isn't any less configurable.